# Angular material password field not rendering properly in IE (latest version)

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I have used angular material to make login form. The text input field works properly, but the password field doesn't render properly in Internet Explorer 11.

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caVHw.png)

Here is the code:

```
 <mat-form-field class="feild-full-width" color="primary">
               <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Username" 
 autocomplete="off" />
            </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="feild-full-width" color="primary">
          <input matInput placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" [type]="texttype ? 'password' : 'text'" />
          <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="texttype = !texttype">{{texttype ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: first remove all to conditional logic from the password field, to check if it renders correctly. if it does, add one by one the conditional items and see where it breaks.